# jQuery not enabling on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, web

I have a problem with my website: jQuery is not working.
I load jQuery in the `<head>` tag before my script.
Do you think it has to do with .htaccess and permissions on the Web server? If it may, I have the following permissions on the index.php file:

```
r-xrwxr-- 574
```

Here is a link to my site: http://hopdog.houa.org

And here is the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>HopDog</title> 
<meta charset ="utf-8" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js" > 

</script> 
<script> 
alert("$"); 
var menuState = "closed"; 
$("#ssl-seal-secure").click(function() { 
       alert("(это для украшения, ясно?)"); 
}); 
$("#shopB").attr("disabled", "true"); 
$("#shop").hide(); 
$("#login").hide(); 
$("#header1").hide(); 
$("#header2").hide(); 
$("#shopB").click(function() { 
      window.location.href("hopdog.houa.org/shop.php"); 
}); 
$("#header3").hide(); 
$("#header4").hide(); 
$("#mainB").hide(); 
                 $("#shopB").hide(); 
                 $("#myButton").hide(); 
$("#hm").click( function() { 
                 if(menuState.indexOf("closed") == 0) { 
                 $("#header1").show(); 
                 $("#header").hide(); 
                 $("#buyG").hide(); 
                 $("#mainB").show(); 
                 $("#shopB").show(); 
                 $("#myButton").show(); 
                 $("#mainB").click(function() { 
location.reload(true); 
}); 
                 $("#myButton").click(function() { 
menuState="turtleLoginState"; 
$("#header3").show(); 
$("#header1").hide(); 
  $("#mainB").hide(); 
                 $("#shopB").hide(); 
                 $("#myButton").hide(); 
$("#login").show(); 
});  
                 menuState = "opened" 
                 } else { 
                     if(menuState.indexOf("turtleLoginState") == 0) { 
                  $("#header1").show(); 
                 $("#header3").hide(); 
                 $("#login").hide(); 
                 $("#buyG").hide(); 
                 $("#mainB").show(); 
                 $("#shopB").show(); 
                 $("#myButton").show(); 
}else{ 
                 menuState = "closed"; 
                 $("#header").show(); 
                 $("#buyG").show(); 
                 $("#header1").hide(); 
                 $("#mainB").hide(); 
                 $("#shopB").hide(); 
                 $("#myButton").hide(); 
} 
} 
}); 
</script> 
<body> 

  <button id="hm"> 
<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icon-part-3/128/menu_hamburger-16.png" style="vertical-align:middle" /> 

</button> <p>HopDog оффициальный сайт</p> 
<div id="body"> 
<p id="header">Главная </p> 
<p id="header1">Меню сайта</p> 
<p id="header2">Магазин</p> 
<p id="header3">Вход</p> 
<p id="header4">Мой аккаунт</p> 
<hr size="2" /> 
<div id="body0"> 
<article> 
<div id="shop"> 
<p>under construction.. Sorry for that...</p> 
</div> 
<div id="login"> 
<input id="loginF" size="15" type="email" value="Имя пользователя" /> 
</br> 
<input id="password" type="password" /> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" /> <button id="reg" > <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-and-office-2-6/65/55-16.png" />Зарегестрироваться</button> 
</div> 
<marquee id="buyG" behavior="alternete" direction="left" bgcolor="#ffffff">Сделайте предзаказ на Old House Story Сейчас!И получите бонусы на ваш счёт!! <span style="color:#006299;">[кликните чтоб попасть В магазин]</span></marquee> 
<input id="mainB" value="Главная" type="button" /> 
<input id="shopB" value="Магазин" type="button" /> 
<input id="myButton" value="Мой Аккаунт" type="button" /> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 
<img id="ssl-seal-secure" src="http://i80.fastpic.ru/thumb/2016/0815/fc/b4c2678de2ab9b4d1260420ddbc1e1fc.jpeg" alt="pseudo-secured by SSL.com (click for more info)" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Any ideas about it?
**Update:**
site fixed, so code changed.

Comment: It loads no problem for me. I see you are attempting to use the code.jquery.com CDN so it's possible your web browser or network is simply blocking it. Try adding jQuery to your web server and source it from your own server. This issue comes up so often for me that I've stopped bothering with CDNs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it would work if you include it at the end of body tag.

Like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Your elements</h1>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>Put your script here.</script>
</body>
```

If it still doesn't work. Maybe try different jquery links.
Like this one https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js

Comment: thanks!that helped.